# Create a 3D snowman

Tags: graphics3d

I'm having to construct a 3D Snowman in Mathematica and I'm having trouble understanding how to create the right arm and eyes for the project. Below is the code that I'm supposed to use to work on the object that creates the snowman, its left arm, hat, one button, and the nose. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
body = Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Sphere[{0, 0, 1.5}, .75], 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 2.7}, .6]}];
button1 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{.75, r Cos[w], r Sin[w] + 1.5}, {r, 0, .1}, {w, 0,
     2 Pi}];
rotZ[w_] := ( {
    {Cos[w], -Sin[w], 0},
    {Sin[w], Cos[w], 0},
    {0, 0, 1}
   } );
rotY[w_] := ( {
    {Cos[w], 0, Sin[w]},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {-Sin[w], 0, Cos[w]}
   } );
rotX[w_] := ( {
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, Cos[w], -Sin[w]},
    {0, Sin[w], Cos[w]}
   } );
armL = Graphics3D[{Thickness[.04], Red, 
    Line[{{0, 0, 1.5}, {.3, 1.6, 2.5}}]}];
hat = ParametricPlot3D[
   rotX[.2].rotY[-.2].{.4 Cos[w], .4 Sin[w], t} + {0, 0, 3}, {w, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {t, 0, .5}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> SurfaceColor[Blue]];
nose = ParametricPlot3D[
   rotY[-.4].rotZ[Pi].{r, .2 r Cos[w], .2 r Sin[w]} + {1.5, 0, 
     3.3}, {r, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> SurfaceColor[Hue[.2]]];
Show[{body, button1, armL, hat, nose}, ViewPoint -> {3, 1, 1}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: How about defining armR analogous to armL and then adding armR to the Show command?

Comment: I tried that but no matter how I manipulate the numbers, I can't seem to get the arm in the correct place.

Answer (score 4):

It would be cool if we could make him dance...In the meantime the following seems a decent stab

```
body = Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Sphere[{0, 0, 1.5}, .75], 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 2.7}, .6]}];
button1 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{.75, r Cos[w], r Sin[w] + 1.5}, {r, 0, .1}, {w, 0,
     2 Pi}];
rotZ[w_] := ({{Cos[w], -Sin[w], 0}, {Sin[w], Cos[w], 0}, {0, 0, 1}});
rotY[w_] := ({{Cos[w], 0, Sin[w]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[w], 0, Cos[w]}});
rotX[w_] := ({{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[w], -Sin[w]}, {0, Sin[w], Cos[w]}});
armL = Graphics3D[{Thickness[.04], Red, 
    Line[{{0, 0, 1.5}, {.3, 1.6, 2.5}}]}];
armR = Graphics3D[{Thickness[.04], Red, 
    Line[{{0, 0, 1.5}, {-.3, -1.6, 2.5}}]}];
hat = ParametricPlot3D[
   rotX[.2].rotY[-.2].{.4 Cos[w], .4 Sin[w], t} + {0, 0, 3}, {w, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {t, 0, .5}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> SurfaceColor[Blue]];
nose = ParametricPlot3D[
   rotY[-.4].rotZ[Pi].{r, .2 r Cos[w], .2 r Sin[w]} + {1.5, 0, 
     3.3}, {r, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> SurfaceColor[Hue[.2]]];
Show[{body, button1, armL, armR, hat, nose}, ViewPoint -> {3, 1, 1}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: snowman]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome :-)